# how can I query to multiple domain's computer account in powershell

Tags: csv, powershell

I have bulk computer list in my CSV file with header of servers.

All these servers are different domains under single forest.

I need to get all these server attribute details like name and operating system, status.

I have created below script but that's not working..

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# For each domain in the forest

$domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains
$servers = Import-Csv "D:\temp\computer.csv" | % {$_.server}

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
  foreach ($domain in $domains)
  {
    Get-ADComputer $server -Server $domain -Properties operatingsystem | select name,operatingsystem 
  }
}
```

#

HI

I have added my script like below:

#

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory



# For each domain in the forest



$domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains

$servers = Import-Csv "D:\temp\computers.csv" | % {$_.server}

$DomainController = "DC2:3268"  #  3268 is the commen port of global catalogue

$SearchBase = ((Get-ADDomain (Get-ADForest).RootDomain).DistinguishedName)

foreach ($server in $servers)

{

foreach ($domain in $domains)

{

Get-ADComputer $server -Server $DomainController -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties operatingsystem | select name,operatingsystem

}
}
```

#

Getting below error now and also I have specified only samaccountname of computer not FQDS this time..

#### Error

```
Get-ADComputer : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'DPS002'.
At D:\temp\search_computer.ps1:34 char:5
+     Get-ADComputer $server -Server $DomainController -SearchBase $SearchBase -Pr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "that's not working". What did you expect? What happened?

Comment: I don't suppose the member domain is a column in your csv?

Answer (score 2):

You have to run your request against the global catalogue to find AD objects in the whole AD forest.

1. You need a server witch is supporting global catalogue.  Choose one which is next to you.

   ```
   Import-Module ActiveDirectory
   @((Get-ADForest).GlobalCatalogs) | Sort-Object
   ```
2. Your script, a little bit modified

   ```
   Import-Module ActiveDirectory
   $DomainController = "ServerFromStep1:3268"  #  3268 is the commen port of global catalogue
   $SearchBase       = ((Get-ADDomain (Get-ADForest).RootDomain).DistinguishedName)

   foreach ($server in $servers)
   {
       Get-ADComputer $server -Server $DomainController -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties operatingsystem | select name,operatingsystem
   }
   ```
3. The same as 2 but able to processed [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)s from server list.

   ```
   foreach ($serverFQDN in $servers)
   {
       $Local:ServerName = (($serverFQDN -replace "\..*$", "").Trim())
       if ($ServerName) {
           Get-ADComputer $ServerName -Server $DomainController -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties operatingsystem | select name,operatingsystem
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi

I have tried script like below but got below error :


Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$DomainController = "DC41:3268"  #  3268 is the commen port of global catalogue
$SearchBase = ((Get-ADDomain (Get-ADForest).RootDomain).DistinguishedName)
$servers = Import-Csv "D:\temp\computers.csv"

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    Get-ADComputer $server -Server $DomainController -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties operatingsystem | select name,operatingsystem
}

Comment: Error is below 

#############ERROR ########

Get-ADComputer : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '@{server=JANCNB.accenture.com}'.
At D:\temp\findallcomputers.ps1:8 char:5
+     Get-ADComputer $server -Server $DomainController -SearchBase $SearchBase -Pr ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer

Comment: It can't work when you are using the FQDN of a server instead of the hostname.  Get-ADComputer doesn't work with FQDNs.  Step 3 shows you the way out of this problem.

Comment: @Mr.Chand please edit the original question and add your comments there as an update, include the version of the script (code) and the error there.